# Listener-level error handler vs Container-level error handler in Spring Kafka

Tags: spring-kafka

With my team, we are trying to set up an error handling policy common to several microservices (for the majority of cases). My team and I are struggling to understand the difference between a listener-level error handler and a container-level error handler. What are the real implications behind this choice? Is it only the fact that the container error handler does not have access to the message?

The KafkaListenerErrorHandler allows a more fine grained exception handling, we can use on the content of the exception to define if it is retryable or not.
In the error handler containers it seems more complicated, before it was possible to provide a custom classifier but not anymore, we can only pass a classification map.

In the past we used to use the SeekToCurrentErrorHandler (now DefaultErrorHandler), which was recommended in the documentation. I saw another StackOverflow thread related to this topic but I can't quite make the connection with our questions. The documentation doesn't seem to address the implications of this choice.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main use case for the listener-level error handler is for request/reply processing; it allows the error handler to send some other result to the sender to indicate the request wasn't processed. As you say, it also provides access to the spring-messaging converted `Message<?>` (possibly with a converted payload); e.g. for logging; it can re-throw the exception to invoke the container EH.

Regarding classification, that change was to allow classifications to be added and removed dynamically. If you prefer to have the old behavior (allowing a custom classifier) to be restored, please open an issue on GitHub.